# jQuery elements (images and divs) are not resizing, when browser windows is resized

Tags: jquery, viewport

I am facing a small problem when the browser window is resized. I am able to get the viewport's width and height and I can set the image size as per the browser window. However when I resize the browser window, the image or the div is not getting resized.

Here is what I have tried to get the viewport's width and height and applied the same to the respective image (element).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// global vars
$(document).ready (function (){
  var winWidth = $ (window).innerWidth();
  var winHeight = $ (window).innerHeight();
  // set initial div height / width
  $('div.background img').css({
    'min-width': winWidth,
    'height': winHeight
  });
  $('.leftstatbar').css({
    'width': '200px',
    'min-height': winHeight
  });
  $(' #firstmenu').css({
    'width': '150px',
    'min-height': winHeight
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('div.background img').css({
      'min-width': winWidth,
      'height': winHeight});
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please help to resolve this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: If that's your whole script, then indenting it properly shows that you're missing a `});` set...

Comment: Thanks i have made corrections to that. However the same is not working still.. Any idea what am i missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code.to resize function

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      var winWidth = $ (window).innerWidth();
      var winHeight = $ (window).innerHeight();
    $('div.background img').css({
      'min-width': winWidth,
      'height': winHeight});
    });
```

In your code problem is... on re sizing you are using values which are calculated at the time of page load.. not after re size...

See http://jsfiddle.net/sL573/

Comment: Hi.. am still not getting it worked, it tried your code. But the image height is not getting adjusted as per browser size. I need to reload it to fit the same to the entire window.. Pls support

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sL573/ check this jsfiddle it does work.. you might need to show other code.. like HTML and css if its not working in your code... a failing jsfiddle will be helpful too..

Comment: Hi.. thanks a lot.. its now working.. I made some changes is CSS and now its working as intended.. Thanks again for all the help